# İnstagram following box not loaded fully via selenium

Tags: html, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, instagram

I try to get my follower's usernames from instagram but I think all my followers does not appear, when I scroll down slowly all my followers appear. Can you help me to solve this problem? When i add

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, './/div[@class="_ab8y  _ab94 _ab97 _ab9f _ab9k _ab9p _abcm"]')))
```

I got timeout error. Also did I add the right class? I'm not sure also I'll add html code. Please help me this makes me mad !

```
followers_panel = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]')
last_ht, ht = 0, 1
while last_ht != ht:
    last_ht = ht
    WebDriverWait(driver, 50).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, './/div[@class="_ab8y  _ab94 _ab97 _ab9f _ab9k _ab9p _abcm"]')))
    # scroll down and retrun the height of scroll
    ht = driver.execute_script(""" 
    arguments[0].scrollTo(0, arguments[0].scrollHeight);
    return arguments[0].scrollHeight; """, followers_panel)

list_of_followers = []
# there must be 54 followers but not all of them are loaded so i is not accurate if it is not loaded thats what i figure out.
i=1
while i<54: 
     list_of_followers.append(driver.find_element_by_xpath(f'/html/body/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[{i}]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/div/a/span/div').text)
     i+=1
```

html code for a follower (the lowest class which includes username as text:

```
<div class=" _ab8y  _ab94 _ab97 _ab9f _ab9k _ab9p _abcm">jackgrealish98</div>
```